# PHP MYSQL Json Issue

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

We have a simple php mysql json api to provide data to android app

We have a fix categories.

so we just check if category is this then fetch result from mysql database and convert in json

Everything is working fine. Fetching url from mysql

```
$stm_row = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Till here all is working fine. data is coming from every category

Then, we convert data to JSON:

```
print(json_encode($stm_row));
```

But the problem is that only 1 catgory data is printing using json, rest category data showing blank

Can you please check what can be issue

Comment: use `foreach` or `loops` in PHP it works

Comment: how to use loop here? Following are my final code. can you edit and add loop how you telling.

Comment: if($stm_row_count>=1)

{

$stm_row = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print(json_encode($stm_row));

}
else
{
 print('jobs not found');
}
}

Answer (score 0):

i am giving you simple demonstration how to work with json.you can try like that

```
$data=array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $data[] = $row['your field name'];
}
echo json_encode(array("response"=>$data));
```

Comment: i am not using MYSQLI, we are using PDO

Comment: i given you demonstration you can change as you want mysqli or pdo

Comment: but the issue is that it will fetch 1 row 1 time. i want all data at once

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through results ...e.g.

```
$stm_row = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

foreach ($stm_row as $row => $cat) {
      echo  $cat['category_name'];
      }
```

OR If you have encoded JSON, need to decode first which will return an array...which you can loop through like ...e.g.

```
$stm_row = json_encode($stm_row);
$arr = json_decode($stm_row, true);

foreach ($arr as $row => $cat) {
      echo  $cat['category_name'];
      }
```

Comment: you do not understand thing. everything is working fine. data is coming in array. but when we use print(json_encode($stm_row)); to display json data then it displaying data for 1 category only. not rest categories

Comment: all in one that print(json_encode($stm_row)); showing blank data

Comment: Do `var_dump($stm_row);` & verify all the categories are there